# SQL - Avoid full scans when joining archive tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

I'm having some performance issues due to full scans being run on some larger tables for a report. I've narrowed things down to this section of the query but can't figure out how to avoid the scans without changing the results.

To explain, we have a data archiving system that copies data from the live table to the archive table daily. The data is not removed from the live table until a period of time has passed. This results in a state where the live table and archive table will both have the same rows, but the data in the rows may not match.

This rules out a UNION query (which would eliminate the full scans). The requirements are for the report to show live data, so I also can't query just the archive table.

Any ideas? Here is the query. The primary keys of both tables is DetailIdent, but I do have an index on OrderIdent, as it's a foreign key back to the parent table. You can see that we take the main table results if they exist, otherwise we fall back to the archive data.

```
SELECT COALESCE(RegOD.OrderIdent, ArcOD.OrderIdent) AS OrderIdent,
                   COALESCE(RegOD.Quantity, ArcOD.Quantity) AS Quantity,
                   COALESCE(RegOD.LoadQuan, ArcOD.LoadQuan) AS LoadQuan,
                   COALESCE(RegOD.ShipQuan, ArcOD.ShipQuan) AS ShipQuan,
                   COALESCE(RegOD.RcvdQuan, ArcOD.RcvdQuan) AS RcvdQuan,
                   COALESCE(RegOD.UOM, ArcOD.UOM) AS UOM,
                   COALESCE(RegOD.SkidType, ArcOD.SkidType) AS SkidType,
                   COALESCE(RegOD.Product, ArcOD.Product) AS Product,
                   COALESCE(RegOD.PkgCode, ArcOD.PkgCode) AS PkgCode
            FROM OrderDetail RegOD
                FULL JOIN dbo.ArcOrderDtl ArcOD
                    ON ArcOD.DetailIdent = RegOD.DetailIdent
                    WHERE COALESCE(RegOD.OrderIdent, ArcOD.OrderIdent) = 717010
```

[image: execution plan showing two clustered index full scans]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filtering predicate `COALESCE(RegOD.OrderIdent,ArcOD.OrderIdent) = 717010` is killing performance and it's forcing the engine to perform a full scan first, and filter data later.

##### Option 1 - Rephrase the COALESCE() function

Rephrase the `COALESCE()` function and let the engine do its work. With a bit of luck the engine will be smart enough to find the optimization. In this case the query can take the form:

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(RegOD.OrderIdent,ArcOD.OrderIdent) AS OrderIdent,
  COALESCE(RegOD.Quantity,ArcOD.Quantity) AS Quantity,
  COALESCE(RegOD.LoadQuan,ArcOD.LoadQuan) AS LoadQuan,
  COALESCE(RegOD.ShipQuan,ArcOD.ShipQuan) AS ShipQuan,
  COALESCE(RegOD.RcvdQuan,ArcOD.RcvdQuan) AS RcvdQuan,
  COALESCE(RegOD.UOM,ArcOD.UOM) AS UOM,
  COALESCE(RegOD.SkidType,ArcOD.SkidType) AS SkidType,
  COALESCE(RegOD.Product,ArcOD.Product) AS Product,
  COALESCE(RegOD.PkgCode,ArcOD.PkgCode) AS PkgCode
FROM OrderDetail RegOD 
FULL JOIN dbo.ArcOrderDtl ArcOD ON ArcOD.DetailIdent = RegOD.DetailIdent
WHERE RegOD.OrderIdent = 717010 or ArcOD.OrderIdent = 717010
```

##### Option 2 - Combine a left join with a right anti-join instead of using a full join

If the engine doesn't optimize Option #1 above, you can still try combining a left join with a right anti-join instead of writing a full join (they are equivalent). It's definitively more verbose, but in this case it clearly shows the engine what to do. This query could look like:

```
SELECT -- left join here
  COALESCE(RegOD.OrderIdent,ArcOD.OrderIdent) AS OrderIdent,
  COALESCE(RegOD.Quantity,ArcOD.Quantity) AS Quantity,
  COALESCE(RegOD.LoadQuan,ArcOD.LoadQuan) AS LoadQuan,
  COALESCE(RegOD.ShipQuan,ArcOD.ShipQuan) AS ShipQuan,
  COALESCE(RegOD.RcvdQuan,ArcOD.RcvdQuan) AS RcvdQuan,
  COALESCE(RegOD.UOM,ArcOD.UOM) AS UOM,
  COALESCE(RegOD.SkidType,ArcOD.SkidType) AS SkidType,
  COALESCE(RegOD.Product,ArcOD.Product) AS Product,
  COALESCE(RegOD.PkgCode,ArcOD.PkgCode) AS PkgCode
FROM OrderDetail RegOD 
LEFT JOIN dbo.ArcOrderDtl ArcOD ON ArcOD.DetailIdent = RegOD.DetailIdent
WHERE RegOD.OrderIdent = 717010
UNION ALL
SELECT -- right anti-join here
  OrderIdent,
  Quantity,
  LoadQuan,
  ShipQuan,
  RcvdQuan,
  UOM,
  SkidType,
  Product,
  PkgCode
FROM dbo.ArcOrderDtl ArcOD
LEFT JOIN OrderDetail RegOD ON ArcOD.DetailIdent = RegOD.DetailIdent
WHERE ArcOD.OrderIdent = 717010 and RegOD.DetailIdent IS NULL
```

Comment: I like it. Option #1 still resulted in the full scans, but option #2 used seeks.

Comment: For option #2, since the second query gets everything only in archive, shouldn't I be able to switch the first query to just look at the main table?

Comment: @Spivonious I don't think so. A full outer join looks at both tables separately. That's why Option #2 spells the optimization out to the engine, so both subqueries can be run  separately, and unioned at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You want all rows for an OrderIdent, but rows (identified by DetailIdent) can be either in OrderDetail or in ArcOrderDtl or both. You want to give precedence to the OrderDetail rows if they exist.

One idea hence is to select all rows and then rank them, giving OrderDetail a better rank than ArcOrderDtl, Use `TOP WITH TIES` then to get all the better ranked rows and dismiss the others.

```
SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES
  OrderIdent, Quantity, LoadQuan, ShipQuan, RcvdQuan, UOM, SkidType, Product, PkgCode
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    DetailIdent, OrderIdent, Quantity, LoadQuan, ShipQuan, RcvdQuan, UOM, SkidType,
    Product, PkgCode, 1 AS priority
  FROM OrderDetail
  WHERE OrderIdent = 717010
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    DetailIdent, OrderIdent, Quantity, LoadQuan, ShipQuan, RcvdQuan, UOM, SkidType,
    Product, PkgCode, 2 AS priority
  FROM dbo.ArcOrderDtl
  WHERE OrderIdent = 717010
) unioned
ORDER BY RANK() (PARTITION BY DetailIdent ORDER BY priority);
```

Comment: I like this one too but it might be hard to incorporate. The query I posted is nested inside of a view.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming both tables share the Primary Key `OrderIdent` and `DetailIdent` (or at least a unique index on those fields). If so, first figure out all keys from the archive table that are not in the live table and then get from both tables the ones we're interested in.

You'll effectively run over both tables twice but the indexes (and caching) will make that fast enough and the operations are very straightforward.

```
SELECT DetailIdent
  INTO #archiveRows
  FROM ArcOrderDtl ArcOD
 WHERE OrderIdent = 717010
 
 EXCEPT 

SELECT DetailIdent
  FROM OrderDetail RegOD
 WHERE OrderIdent = 717010
 
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX uq0_archiveRows ON #archiveRows (DetailIdent) WITH (FILLFACTOR = 100)

SELECT -- live
  OrderIdent,
  Quantity,
  LoadQuan,
  ShipQuan,
  RcvdQuan,
  UOM,
  SkidType,
  Product,
  PkgCode,
FROM OrderDetail RegOD 
WHERE RegOD.OrderIdent = 717010

UNION ALL

SELECT -- archive
  OrderIdent,
  Quantity,
  LoadQuan,
  ShipQuan,
  RcvdQuan,
  UOM,
  SkidType,
  Product,
  PkgCode
FROM dbo.ArcOrderDtl ArcOD
JOIN #archiveRows t
  ON t.DetailIdent = ArcOD.DetailIdent
WHERE ArcOD.OrderIdent = 717010
```

PS: If you can't use temp-tables for some reason I guess you could put it in a CTE instead; going by the low number of actual rows returned that should work fine too I guess. (I mostly tend to 'promote' temp-tables because they are easy to read, can be indexed and the optimizer will create statistics on them and use that for the next steps!)

Comment: Just reread the OP and notice that the PK is just on `DetailIdent` meaning the last `WHERE ArcOD.OrderIdent = 717010` is actually  superfluous. Then again, I doubt you'll notice =)

Comment: Nice suggestion, but unfortunately this query is buried in a view so temp tables aren't a realistic option (although I suppose a TVF could come into play).

Comment: @Spivonious Like I said, you can easily move the temp-table part to a Common Table Expression or even a sub-query if you prefer; that way incorporating this into an existing view shouldn't be too hard. You'll need to forego on the CREATE INDEX off course but given the amount of data here that shouldn't be an issue.